# How to use a route for more than one contenttype?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm attempting to make a contenttype specific route, like [the example in the bolt documentation](https://docs.bolt.cm/templates-routes#contenttype-overrides):

```
pagebinding:
  path:           /{slug}
  defaults:
      _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::record'
      'contenttypeslug': page
  requirements:
      'contenttypeslug': 'Bolt\Controllers\Routing::getAnyContentTypeRequirement'
```

But operating on multiple contenttypes ("pages" and "users" specifically).

In other words, I'd like to do something like this:

```
pagebinding:
  path:           /{slug}
  defaults:
      _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::record'
      'contenttypeslug': page, user
  requirements:
      'contenttypeslug': 'Bolt\Controllers\Routing::getAnyContentTypeRequirement'
```

<sup>This particular example doesn't work, giving a 404 error when e.g. `domain.tld/page, user/somepage` isn't found.</sup>

So that both `domain.tld/somepage` and `domain.tld/username` work,
assuming `somepage` is the slug of a "page" record, and `username` is the slug of a "user" record.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't. There can be only one contenttype that has `/{slug}`.

Say you have a user 'x', and a page 'x'. Somebody goes to 'domain.tld/x', there's no way to know which is which. Just make the users have a logical URL like `/user/x`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought perhaps there was a way to ensure the slugs of both contenttypes were unique (e.g. appending a number when a collision occurs), but I guess not.